# Last value in list displaying on PrintPreview and PrintOut for each iteration

Tags: dynamic, printing

Two worksheets, one the form, one with a list of names.  When testing the code using printPreview, each iteration of the form displaying the last name in the list where as I am expecting each instance to have a unique element from the list.

Sub PrintPlanners()

Dim i As Long, LastRow As Long

LastRow = Worksheets("Names").Range("A7").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To LastRow
If Not Worksheets("Names").Range("A" & i).Value = 0 Then
Worksheets("Planner").Range("B4").Value = Worksheets("Names").Range("A" & i).Value
Worksheets("Planner").PrintPreview
End If
Next i

End Sub